# como hacer para que entre en el while sin dar bucle infinito (python)

Tags: python

lo que intento con el try, es que si escribís un numero te meta en el while(ponele si le pongo !=str se mete en un bucle infinito, y si pongo ==int no entra), como lo harían ustedes. (pd: perdón por no saber explicarme bien)

```
def x(qe):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    try:                                                                                                                                                  
        q=input(qe)                                                                                                                                        
        while q!=str:                                                                                                                                     
            q=input(qe)
        print("funciona")
    except typeError:
        print("ingresaste cualquier cosa")
    return q    
w='introduce tu nombre:'
w=x(w)
print(w)
if w=="hola":
    print("hola")
```

Comment: utiliza `type(q) == int` (aunque tampoco te funcionará)

Comment: que es lo que hace tu código? o que intentas hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Si no entiendo mal, lo que quieres es que se le pida nuevamente el dato en caso haya ingresado un numero, para eso tenemos que convertir el `input` a entero con la función `int()`. Lo que tu estas haciendo, es comparar el dato con el tipo de dato (objeto) lo cual no es muy correcto, para comparar tipos de datos debe usar la función `type()` para obtener el tipo de dato del objeto, luego si podras comparar entre datos, pero si usas esto en tu código el resultado de `type(q)` siempre será `str` ya que el input devuelve un string.

Para solucionar esto simplemento convertimos la entrada (input) a entero con `int()` si hay un error significa que es un string y si no lo hay significa que es un entero (numero), tu codigo se puede reducir, pero no lo hice, dejaré tu lógica.

```py
def x(qe):          
    while True:
        q = input(qe)
        try:                                                                                                                                                  
            q = int(q) #convertimos a entero
            print("funciona") #se ejecuta si el input es un numero
        except: #se ejecuta el bloque en caso sea una cadena
            print("ingresaste cualquier cosa")
            break #detenemos el bucle
    return q    
w='introduce tu nombre:'
w=x(w)

print(w)
if w=="hola":
    print("hola")
```

Comment: wow me lo respondiste rapidísimo ,muchas gracias Christian

Answer (score 1):

Hola creo entender que lo que necesitas es saber si ha introducido un numero no??
Para eso todos los String en Python tienen un método que te dice si es un numero:

```
txt = "10223"
if txt.isnumeric():
     print("Es un número")
```

tienes otros métodos como isdecimal(), isalpha() para solo letras, isalnum() para alfanumericos etc etc...

Por lo tanto yo para tu codigo usaría el ISALPHA ya que creo que es lo que quieres, que solo pueda introducir nombres...

```
def x(qe):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                       
    q=input(qe)                                                                                                                                        
    while not q.isalpha():
        print("Has introducido un numero o sabe dios que...")                                                                                                                                     
        q=input(qe)
    print("funciona")
    
    return q    

w='introduce tu nombre:'
w=x(w)

print(w)
if w=="hola":
    print("hola")
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias !!!!!!!!